# MotionLayout swipe without snapping to states?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-motionlayout

I've noticed that all the MotionLayouts so far always snap to one of their end states, even if you drag a view halfway through the animation, stop, and let go. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the motionlayout only act on user interaction and momentum. If the user lets go in the middle of an animation it should stop completely once momentum runs out and not keep interpolating until an explicitly defined state, which is the default behaviour.

Lists, scrollviews, coordinatorlayouts all support this "halfway" stop, so why not motionlayout?

So does anyone knows how to freeze the progress of a motionlayout between states? It should work for any position on the timeline so I don't want to add extra states, as it would require a 100 of them.

Answer (score 9):

Add an `onTouchUp` to your `OnSwipe`. `stop` is probably what you want. `decelerate` seems to be buggy. And stop is more of a deceleration anyways if it's connected to a scrolling view since the view will provide its own deceleration.

```
    <OnSwipe
        app:dragDirection="dragUp"
        app:onTouchUp="stop"
        app:touchAnchorId="@id/scrollView"
        app:touchAnchorSide="top" />
```

Found this here: https://mikescamell.com/motionlayoutquickie-ontouchup/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position with `motionLayout.setProgress()` method, and do it or when the transition is changing or when you release your finger - on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP in the OnTouch method.

First variant:

```
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(new MotionLayout.TransitionListener() {

        // Other methods

        @Override
        public void onTransitionChange(MotionLayout motionLayout, int i, int i1, float v) {
            // v == motionLayout.getProgress();
            motionLayout.setProgress(v);
        }

        // Other methods
    });
```

Second variant:

```
if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    motionLayout.setProgress(motionLayout.getProgress());
}
```